# Mortar: How-to use Presenter for List Item/Adapter

Tags: android, mortar

I using a List with Custom Adapter with ViewHolder and Item Views with Buttons. 
I want to handle some stuff by clicking the Buttons in a Presenter.

How can i connect a Presenter with these Item Views?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [rx-android](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid) to observe AdapterView's click events the following way. It combines fine with MVP pattern used in Mortar.
At first dependencies:

```
compile 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.0.4'    
compile 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:0.24.0'
```

Then create `observeClicks` method in your view class.

```
public Observable<OnItemClickEvent> observeClicks() {
    return WidgetObservable.itemClicks(adapterView);
}
```

Subscribe to events in your Presenter's `onLoad`:

```
private Subscription clicks;

@Override
protected void onLoad() {
    super.onLoad();
    clicks = getView().observeClicks().subscribe(
        new Action1<OnItemClickEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void call(OnItemClickEvent event) {
                // handle click events 
            }
        }
    );
}

protected void onDestroy() {
    // unsubscribe from events
    clicks.unsubscribe();
}
```

Also you can do mapping `OnItemClickEvent` to your data inside view already and observe it instead of raw events.

```
public Observable<YourDataClass> observeClicks() {
    return WidgetObservable.itemClicks(adapterView).
           map(new Func1<OnItemClickEvent, YourDataClass>() {
                @Override
                public YourDataClass call(OnItemClickEvent onItemClickEvent) {
                     YourDataClass item = adapter.getItem(onItemClickEvent.position());
                     return item;
                }
           });
}
```

Hope this comes in handy. At least I'm doing this that way, but certainly it is not the only solution.

Answer (score -1):

```
ListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Handle your stuff here.
    });
```

Something like this? Use the position to get the current item out of your List.

Buttons :

```
// In the adapter
Button butt = (Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.yourbutton);
butt.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //Button Action.
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't want to listen to the whole item. Instead to the Buttons in this View.

Comment: But i don't want to handle the Action in the Adapter. I want to handle it in a Presenter

Comment: What is this Presenter you're talking about? Show me some code you have.

Comment: Might add a ListView to the constructor of the Presenter, this way you can use the onItemClick in the Presenter? Otherwise I wouldn't know either, sorry.

Comment: I you don't know how Mortar works, please write nothing rather than some random guessing answer.